# Starting and stopping node.js server from windows batch file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for a way to stop a node.js's server from a batch file. For eg: I have a batch file called `start.bat` in which I am starting node.js server like this `node c:\test.js`, so this will start server on port 8080, similarly I would like to stop that `test.js` server from another batch file called `stop.bat`. How can I do this?

I tried looking into many similar questions in SO, but all of them uses start and stop from the same .js file.

So is this possible? If yes, can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use forever to start and stop the server: https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever

first install it globally:

```
npm install -g forever
```

run the server:

```
forever start test.js
```

stop the server:

```
forever stop test.js
```

of course you can also put this script in a .bat file :)

Comment: Hi, one quick help, whenever I try to run this command, node.exe opens a new window. Is it possible to hide it?

Comment: forever seems to have some incompatibility on windows, alternative approach: in start.bat "node test.js"; in stop.bat "taskkill /IM node.exe"

Answer (score 1):

I was just playing around with the same functionality. I managed to start node without opening a cmd window by launching it with a .vbs

This a script I patched together that will start your server and then launch chrome on your localhost:

```
 Dim objWshShell, ls, lc
 set objWshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 ls = objWshShell.Run("cmd /k cd C:\the\path\to\your\server && node myServer.js", 0, false)
 lc = objWshShell.Run("chrome localhost:8080", 1, false)
 set objWshShell = nothing
```

By passing a 0 in the first run command myServer.js will launch without a cmd window. I am sure that something link this could be adapted to give you the functionality your are looking for!